# How can I update keycloak's user details programmatically (java), without using rest admin api?

Tags: java, rest, keycloak

I want to update the user detail. e.g. I created user(k1) in "demo" realm from keycloak admin console. I have one java client and I want to update the user(k1) details like. Change Email address of user k1.

I did using Admin client(Rest API) as below.

```
public void updateEmail(final String newEmailAddress) {
    try {
        final AccessToken accessToken = getToken();
        Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder().serverUrl(this.getDeployment().getAuthServerBaseUrl())
                .realm(this.getDeployment().getRealm()).username("k1").password("123").clientId(ADMIN_CLIENT)
                .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build()).build();

        UserResource userResource = keycloak.realm(this.getDeployment().getRealm()).users()
                .get(accessToken.getSubject());
        UserRepresentation user = userResource.toRepresentation();
        user.setEmail(newEmailAddress);
        userResource.update(user);

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I want do the same without using Admin client.

Comment: How would do it without the REST client ? It's not possible, or you use the console or the REST endpoints ...

Comment: I was using the admin account to update user's email.i.e. keycloak admin client. and i was needed another way.

Comment: Did you find more information about what is the recommended way to let users update their info with the access token without using admin credentials? I've been looking around and couldn't find it for now.

Comment: Two options are presented in this answer, [update-own-profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298170/allowing-a-user-to-update-their-own-profile-using-the-rest-api), user-service or account profile theme.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jsoup-1.6.0.jar for updating any user's detail as follow.

```
public boolean updateAccountDetails(String name, String value) 
{
String url= getKeycloakAdapter().getDeployment().getAccountUrl();

Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
if (document != null) {
  String formQuery = String.format("form[action^=%s]", url);
  Elements form = document.select(formQuery);
  if (!form.isEmpty()) {
    Elements inputs = form.select("input[value], input:not([disabled])");
    Element saveAction = form.select("button[value=Save]").first();
    inputs.add(saveAction);
    Map<String, String> mandatoryArguments = new HashMap<>();
    for (Element input : inputs) {
      mandatoryArguments.put(input.attr("name"), input.attr("value"));
    }
    mandatoryArguments.put(attributeName, newValue);
    Response response = Jsoup.connect(accountUrl)
        .data(mandatoryArguments)
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

    Document finalDoc = response.parse();
    if (finalDoc != null) {
      Elements finalForm = finalDoc.select(formQuery);
      if (finalForm != null) {
        String newValueQuery = String.format("input[name=%s], input[value=%s]", name, value);
        Elements finalInputs = finalForm.select(newValueQuery);
        if (finalInputs != null) {
          return !finalInputs.isEmpty();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
throw new IOException("Account page not found");
```

}

Comment: As a policy, "there are no bad answers".

Answer (score -1):

I did it Using Following approach.

```
    public void updateEmail(final String newEmailAddress)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, HttpFailure, VerificationException {

    List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<>();

    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stateChecker", "QW1iwts0YS8pC0JDosACq-2ZAJHtTW8HWN7KSgTV8rc"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "5somebody@gmail.com"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName", "1some"));
    formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastName", "1body"));

    KeycloakDeployment deployment = this.getDeployment();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/account/");
    ClientCredentialsProviderUtils.setClientCredentials(deployment, post, formparams);
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    post.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.getTokenString(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

    UrlEncodedFormEntity form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
    post.setEntity(form);

    HttpResponse response = deployment.getClient().execute(post);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        print(response.getEntity().getContent());
    } else {
        print(response.getEntity().getContent());
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());
    }
}
```

To get this above thing done I need to change my account.ftl(which is present at location  ***:***\keycloak-demo-3.1.0.Final\keycloak\themes\base\account\account.ftl) as follows

```
    <#if stateChecker??>
        <input type="hidden" id="stateChecker" name="stateChecker" value="${stateChecker?html}">
    <#else>
        <input type="hidden" id="stateChecker" name="stateChecker" value=" ">
    </#if>
```

The reason behind change was ,I was getting error like:

Failed to process template: org.keycloak.theme.FreeMarkerException: Failed to process template account.ftl